# Not necessary always add an attchment

Tags: c#

My program is a type e-mail and sometimes i want insert an attachment other times i dont.
So when i dont want insert attachments show me an error

```
Additional information: The 'fileName' parameter can not be an empty string.
```

this is my code of my program.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Anexostxt.Text));
    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(anexos2.Text));  
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

    if(dlg.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string picpath = dlg.FileName.ToString();
        Anexostxt.Text = picpath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are these two different buttons? Why are you attaching two attachments at a time?

Comment: if i want insert 2 attachs i insert them in 2 textbox, no? or exist another solution?

Comment: Why two though? What if you only want to insert one? It seems odd to insert two at a time - particularly when your question talks about inserting *an* attachment.

Comment: so?? if i watn insert 2 attach what i do?

Comment: If you *always* want to insert two attachments, that's fine - but your question didn't say anything about that. Basically, your question is unclear in general - please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your error!

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Anexostxt.Text) && File.Exists(Anexostxt.Text))    
        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Anexostxt.Text));
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(anexos2.Text) && File.Exists(anexos2.Text)) 
        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(anexos2.Text));  
}
```

Comment: the name File and msg doesnt current exist  in this current context :/

Comment: @BrunoGonçalves this is actually your code with a little if statement. If it doesn't work, then go back and learn some basics of c#

Comment: i know that men but the string msg is not declarated in this button so i need to declare?

Comment: @BrunoGonçalves: Well you've got `msg.Attachments.Add` in the code you posted in the question, so why would it not work now?

Comment: i cut some code...
SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Anexostxt.Text));
            msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(anexos2.Text));